# My flash message view on web page and if do dd its also not get session value in blade page.?

Tags: php, laravel

Before my Flash massage was seen .but since I create cart in `session` after that flash massages stop work . if I do `session` `dd` it's show text but it's not seen in view page . I used laravel 5.8.
This is my `blade.php` code

```
@if(Session::has('cc'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">*</button>
        <strong>{{ session('cc')}}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
@if(Session::has('coc'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">*</button>
        <strong>{{ session('coc')}}</strong>
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>
                {{$error}}
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

This is my controller Code

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{   //validations
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:20|min:3',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'companyname' => 'required|max:20|min:3',
        'description' => 'required',

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Session::flash('coc','Posts not created');
        return redirect('products/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    } 
    //save value of product in table
    $post = new Product;
    $post->name = $request->name;
    $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $post->price = $request->price;
    $post->companyname = $request->companyname;
    $post->description = $request->description;
    $post->save();
    // Session::flash('cc','Product is created');
    // dd(session::all());
    return back()->with(['cc'=> 'Product is created']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
@if (\Session::has('cc'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">*</button>
        <strong>{!! \Session::get('cc') !!}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

In your controller -

```
return redirect()->back()->with('cc', ['Product is created']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for me, and it works perfectly:

**FRONT**

```
@if(session('flash_message'))
    <div id="flash_message" style="padding: 20px 30px; background: {{ session('success') ? 'green' : 'red' }}; z-index: 999999; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600;">
        <a class="pull-right" onclick="el=document.getElementById('flash_message');el.parentNode.removeChild(el);" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Never show me this again!" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px;">×</a>
        <span style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px; text-decoration: none;">{{ session()->get('flash_message') }}</span>
    </div>
@endif
```

**BACK**

```
return redirect()->route('items.index')->with([
    'success' => true,
    'flash_message' => "The Items has been successfully created.",
]);
```